# Finding adjacent matrix: Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to find all adjacent elements in the matrix. Adjacent refers to elements being right beside each other either horizontal, vertical and diagonal elements. However it is giving me `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5`. I am not sure why, any help would be much appreciated! Also the program needs to be recursive !

```
class matrixAdjacent
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      char grid[][] = {{'0','0','0','1','1','0','1','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1'},
                      {'1','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'},
                      {'0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1'},
                      {'1','1','1','0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','1','0','1','1','0','1','1','0'},
                      {'0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1','0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1','0','1'}};
      
      ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, 0, 0);
   }


private static void ExploreAndLabelColony(char[][] grid, int i, int j) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(grid==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(i==grid.length || j==grid[0].length) 
    {
        return;
    }  
    
    if (grid[i][j] == '1') //checks if theres a 1 which refers to a colony      
    {
      if (i>0 && i + 1 < grid.length && j>0 && j + 1 < grid[0].length) 
      {
         if (grid[i+1]==grid[j] || grid[i] == grid[j+1] || grid[i-1]==grid[j] || grid[i]==grid[j-1]) //checks if adjacent
         {
           grid[i][j] = 'A'; //creates a colony
         }
      }
    }
    else if(grid[i][j] == '0') //replaces 0 with '-'
    {
      grid[i][j] = '-';  
    }
    
    System.out.print(grid[i][j]); //print grid
    if(j==grid[0].length-1)
    {
      System.out.println();      //prints next row
      ExploreAndLabelColony(grid,i+1,0); //recurse to increment row 
    }     
    ExploreAndLabelColony(grid,i,j+1); //recurse to increment column
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issues

```java
      if (i>0 && i + 1 < grid.length && j>0 && j + 1 < grid[0].length) 
      {
         if (grid[i+1]==grid[j] || grid[i] == grid[j+1] || grid[i-1]==grid[j] || grid[i]==grid[j-1]) //checks if adjacent
         {
           grid[i][j] = 'A'; //creates a colony
         }
      }
```

In the above section of code, `j>0 && j + 1 < grid[0].length` can not guarantee the access to `grid[j]`.

The check on inner array index can not correctly validate the access to outer array index.

### Check adjacent elements

To check adjacent elements, all 4 valid adjacent indices have to be checked

1. `grid[i][j - 1]`
2. `grid[i][j + 1]`
3. `grid[i - 1][j]`
4. `grid[i + 1][j]`

In the above 4 checks, please validate the index before making any of the `i - 1`, `i + 1`, `j - 1`, `j + 1` access.

Comment: How do i fix this? I tried to make the condition on the same line but it still gives me errors

Comment: @some_cs_student, updated the answer with possible indices. You can debug using your code debugger. If you not using any debugger, you can try intellij community edition.

Answer (score 0):

For the given cell with coordinates `i`, `j` the adjacent elements are in the square:

```
[i - 1][j - 1], [i - 1][j], [i - 1][j + 1]
[i    ][j - 1],  CURR_CELL, [i    ][j + 1]
[i + 1][j - 1], [i + 1][j], [i + 1][j + 1]
```

Additional limitations may be applied using `Math.min`, `Math.max` functions and adjacent cells can be detected as follows:

```java
if (grid[i][j] == '1') {  //checks if theres a 1 which refers to a colony
    out: // label to break
    for (int ii = Math.max(i - 1, 0), in = Math.min(grid.length, i + 2); ii < in; ii++) {
        for (int jj = Math.max(j - 1, 0), jn = Math.min(grid[0].length, j + 2); jj < jn; jj++) {
            if (ii == i && jj == j) {
                continue; // skip reference cell
            }
            if (grid[ii][jj] == '1') {
                grid[i][j] = 'A';
                break out; // as soon as the first neighbor is found
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this change, the output for the given input:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char grid[][] = {
        {'0','0','0','1','1','0','1','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1'},
        {'1','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'},
        {'0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1'},
        {'1','1','1','0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','1','0','1','1','0','1','1','0'},
        {'0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1','0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1','0','1'}
    };
      
    ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, 0, 0);
}
```

is as follows:

```
---AA-A1---AA1-AAA-A
A----A---A-----AAAAA
-A--A---A-1------AAA
AAA--A-A----A-AA-AA-
-AA1-AA1-1--1-1-A1-1
```

Possibly, condition should be fixed to check if adjacent cell is already containing `A`, or if there are too many neighbors but setting/applying these or any other rules is up to the author.

Comment: @some_cs_student, you may want to read the following page [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)